# environment variables for julia 1.0

Tags: julia

I would like to have .julia under julia-1.0.0 directory so that I can copy entire julia installation to an offline machine.

what are the environment associated variables ? For 0.6 there used to be

```
JULIA_PKGDIR
JULIA_HOME
LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Tried setting these, still have an issue:

```
julia> LOAD_PATH
1-element Array{String,1}:
 "/share/apps/Julia/julia-1.0.0/.julia/"

julia> DEPOT_PATH
1-element Array{String,1}:
 "/share/apps/Julia/julia-1.0.0/.julia/"

julia> using Pkg
ERROR: ArgumentError: Package Pkg not found in current path:
- Run `Pkg.add("Pkg")` to install the Pkg package.

Stacktrace:
 [1] require(::Module, ::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:817
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [julia 1.0 Pkg add and build work but using fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249031/julia-1-0-pkg-add-and-build-work-but-using-fails)

Comment: Although it is not 100% solution, you could consider to use workaround: if you move .julia on your online machine to share:  `mv  ~/.julia /share/apps/Julia/julia-1.0.0/.julia/` and then create symlink: `ln -s /share/apps/Julia/julia-1.0.0/.julia/ ~/.julia` then your newly installed packages will be physically placed in your share. (old packages too because you moved them in first step ;) )

Answer (score 3):

`JULIA_LOAD_PATH` and `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH`. See the [documentation](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/latest/) of the new package manager.

Comment: In particular, the glossary of Pkg.jl contains the explanation of `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH`: https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1.1/glossary/.

Answer (score 1):

your `*_PATH`s should have more entries:

```
> LOAD_PATH
 3-element Array{String,1}:
  "@"
  "@v#.#"
  "@stdlib"

> DEPOT_PATH
 3-element Array{String,1}:
  "/home/no/.julia"
  "/home/no/.julia/julia-1.0.0/local/share/julia"
  "/home/no/.julia/julia-1.0.0/share/julia"
```

It looks like you overwrote the default values and now julia cant find the other packages.

Also, (at least for my installation on ubuntu/wsl), if you just unpack the julia installation to a folder it'll do its magic there and you can copy that folder, ie `.julia`.

Comment: While doing a "add <package>", how do I tell julia to install this package under share/julia instead of .julia/... ?

Comment: I recommend reading the docs crstnbr referenced, but if I am understanding your question correctly, you want everything to be stored within your julia-1.0.0 directory, so that would involve making a new depot there, or to where-ever your want the files to be installed, and then modifying the `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` environment

Comment: I tried  DEPOT_PATH=circshift(DEPOT_PATH,1) so that /share/julia comes first. but then I get cannot assign error. JULIA_DEPOT_PATH is empty in the shell. If I set it to new depot path, I am back again where I lose other elements of DEPOT_PATH

Comment: Apparently it is not as well defined as I would have imagined. See [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/where-or-how-to-edit-depot-path/13501/14) for more details. One solution is to `push!(DEPOT_PATH, "/address/to/wherever")`, and add that to `julia-1.0.0/etc/julia/startup.jl`. You could also simply add a link from ~/.julia to your desired path. Both seem ... hacky